# mysql_fetch_array not working for 1 row query result

Tags: php, mysql

My query works fine. but wen trying get unique value from the table mysql fetch array not work.

this is my sql 
A-2815 is the item code of the vehicle. this field is unique. Expecting result is item_code A-2815 's vehicle details.

```
$sql  = "SELECT vehicle.id, item_code, make, model, vehicle_type, color, showroom_id, "; 
$sql .= "adding_user_Id, approved, image_1 ";
$sql .= "FROM  images,  vehicle ";
$sql .= "WHERE vehicle.id=images.item_id ";
$sql .= "AND (item_code LIKE '%A-2815%' ";
$sql .= "OR  make LIKE '%A-2815%' ";
$sql .= "OR model LIKE '%A-2815%' ";
$sql .= "OR vehicle_type LIKE '%A-2815%' ";
$sql .= "OR color LIKE '%A-2815%' ";
$sql .= "OR showroom_id LIKE '%A-2815%') "; 
$sql .= "AND activate=1 ";
$sql .= "AND type_of_image=1 ";
```

this is my  php code.

```
<?php
      $query = mysql_query($sql);
      while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
           echo $result['item_code'];
           echo $result['make'];
           echo $result['model'];
           echo $result['vehicle_type'];
           echo $result['color'];
           echo $result['showroom_id'];
      }
 ?>
```

this working ok when results are more then 1 row. but problem is when result is 1 row then it is not working.

Comment: Can you provide the result of single record which is not displaying

Comment: The 'mysql' extension is deprecated it seems as of 5.5.0? See the [PHP.net Manual Page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) for more details.

Comment: You could also use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to build your Query. It would remove the repetitive step to keep adding a new string to an existing variable.

Comment: Use PDO or mysqli_*. Consult [this.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/)

Comment: I have wacking my brain out to resolve this problem, but nothing helped me. Have anyone solution or any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    // assoc
    echo $result['item_code'];
}
```

MySQLi solution for this

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pwd', 'dbname');

$sql = "select * from sometable";

$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // assoc
    echo $result['item_code'];
}
```

Comment: Is 'MYSQL_BOTH' not the default for mysql_fetch_array()?